# Does the YouTube App on the Nexus 10 allow the selection of a default video playback resolution?

Tags: youtube, samsung-nexus-10

Does anyone know if you can set the default playback resolution on the YouTube app?  I can do this on my Motorola RAZR V phone, but can't do it on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.  Can I set it on the Nexus 10?  Does anyone know of any other Android tablet that allows the selection of the default video resolution in the YouTube app?